# Symfony - $request->getSession() = null

Tags: php, symfony, session, request

Since day we are getting a php error from Google's ip's:

```
[client 66.249.xx.xx:xxxx] Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function get() on null in /usr/home/project/myProject/src/AppBundle/Service/LocaleListener.php:22
```

It seems that Symfony's `$request->getSession()` returns null sometimes. Can't figure out the reason. Here's where error occurs:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if (!empty($request->getSession()->get('_locale'))) {
        return;
    }
...
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With symfony you define firewalls, by default a user is authenticated only under one firewall.

For example `security.yml`:

```
   firewalls:
    secondfirewall:
        pattern:  ^/secondfirewall
        provider: broker

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

I assume your user is logged under the **main** firewall

You'll have a session on all urls except them starting by **/secondfirewall**. This might explain why you don't get a session

To debugging which route is going into error you could add log to your listener and exit if no session available.

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if(null === $request->getSession()) {
        // Log everything you want to debug, url, paremeters, body content etc
        // Then you can redirect the user to the login page 
        return new RedirectResponse('someloginurl');
        // Or you can just exit from your listener
        return;
    }
    if (!empty($request->getSession()->get('_locale'))) {
        return;
    }
...
}
```

If as you mentionned in the comment the call which go into error are Google's robot calls, you could log :

```
$request->headers->get('User-Agent') -> check the returned string,
```

Do a regex with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php) to exit from listener if it match the google's user agent.

Moreover you could configure the pages which google robots will parse with the robot.txt file, please check [google documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en) to controle the urls to crawl

Comment: I will debug as you comment, but the problem does not come from users. It is always for the same IP range (66.249.XX.XX) which seems to be google's range. Maybe they are crawlers, but I think it's adwords bot, because it is throwing those errors only on pages with adwords campaigns. Maybe are google bots using CLI like client?

Comment: We have robots.txt configured. As said, it seems that is coming from adwords bots. I'll try to use your answer edit to figure out which type of client is causing this error to find a final solution. Marked yours as accepted!

Comment: Thank you ! Check this link for a good list of different Google's user agents : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You won't have a session for all requests. If it's from CLI for example. Also unless for some reason it's been designed that way, a "traditional" API request won't either.